# Unexpected behavior with dplyr :: filter()

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Thank you for your time. This may seem obvious but I am trying to filter() a column named `_STATE`. However I keep getting an “unexpected input error” within my code. I am assuming it has to do with the underscore in front of `STATE`. I tried to change the name of the column but still can’t get this to work. Any suggestions on to bypass this error? See below for code and error

```r
library(dplyr)
Q2 <- BRFSS2015 %>%
  filter(_STATE == "42")

Q2
#Error: unexpected input in:
# "Q2 <- BRFSS2015 %>%
# filter(_"
```

Comment: Ellie, a part of @akrun's answer, please be aware that sometimes functions can be the same name from different packages, and with different purpose. This seems not to be the case, but you can avoid function's names conflict by adding the package name along with the functions, i.e. `dplyr::filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The `_` at the beginning is unusual column name.  It needs to be backticked

```
library(dplyr)
Q2 <- BRFSS2015 %>% 
   filter(`_STATE` == "42")
```

Comment: So that kinda works, however then it just says there are no results basically. Even though looking at the raw data there is clearly data. Suggestions?

Comment: @EllieBrewers you need to assign i.e. `Q2 <-`..  Regarding why it is  not returning any row, it could be because there are are no value that matches "42".  Please check if there are leading/lagging spaces

Comment: @EllieBrewers can you update your post with the `dput(head(BRFSS2015))`

Comment: Besides, maybe it's not a `character`, but a `numeric`. So you'd use `Q2 <- BRFSS2015 %>%  filter(`_STATE` == 42)` instead.

Comment: @patL that shouldn't be a problem because it could coerce to that type.  The OP didn't provide any example, so it is hard to understand the real reason

Comment: Thank you everyone who commented! All were helpful. I ended up being able to do what the first comment suggested and put back-slashes denoting ‘_STATE’. I just wiped what I had prior and then rewrote the code. And it worked. So somewhere it there must have been leading/ lagging spaces that messed with the filter function. Once again thank you all for the help, I greatly appreciate it.